# "could sought" in a conditional statement

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I am asking my friend for a favor. If he doesnot accept then i have to inform him that i will look for someone else to favor me. For this context, i am confused with using could and should or would in future sense.

> If not, reply me so that i could sought for others!

Did the sentence conveyed what i expected?

I am little bit confused about future perfect tense and present perfect tense!

Thanks in advance

---

### Update based on answers

So

> Could is the 'past' form of can. It expresses past tense in 'real' mode, or non-past tense in 'unreal' mode, but it cannot express non-past in real mode. **You have to use can**.

But the next answer suggests

> If not, reply to me so that I could seek help from others

I will look for next person if he denied and i am not sure whether he will deny or not. So that `could seek` depends on a event that has yet to occur. So following infinitive form of the verb after `could` expresses **the context in present or future** ?

Comment: Regarding your update, "...so that I can seek..." would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are no perfects here - the perfect is constructed with the past participle preceded by a form of *have*.
2. A modal (*can/could*, *may/must*, *shall/should*, *will/would*) must be followed by a verb in the infinitive (plain) form: *seek* in this context. But *seek* is very stiff and formal - in ordinary speech we say *look for*
3. *Could* is the 'past' form of *can*. It expresses past tense in 'real' mode, or non-past tense in 'unreal' mode, but it cannot express non-past in real mode. You have to use *can*.
4. *Reply* requires the preposition *to* for the person addressed. Again, it is pretty formal; in ordinary speech we would say *tell me* or *let me know*.
5. *Others*, too, is pretty formal; we would say *someone else* or *somebody else.*

So what you want to say is something more like:

> If not, let me know, so I can look for somebody else.

Comment: Thanks mentioning various forms of verb i didn't knew about them. New learning :). Edited post depending on answer and need more clarifications

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say:

> If not, reply *to* me so that *I* could *seek help from* others!

You can replace *help* with *a favor* if you like.
There are several changes here, but regarding your main question, you cannot use *sought* because the action *help* is not in the past, as it has not happened yet.

Also, since this is a reply to your request, an exclamation point (!) may not be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks about mentioning exclamation. It's my bad habit of putting ! at end of sentences :(

Answer (score 0):

After a modal verb such as can/could only  a bare infinitive or a bare infinitive perfect can follow. Other structures are not possible.

Possible: can seek, could seek - can have sought, could have sought

Not possible: can sought, could sought

By the way, you could say: If you don't give me an answer I'll ask other people.

Answer (score 0):

Or, more elegantly:
"if not, please reply, so that I might seek [the favor] (of/from) someone else."
(This is a bit formal, but actually more apt than "can" or "could" since you could seek the favor of someone else whether or not the first person replies.)